# Passing Jinja variables in airflow params dict

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, mwaa

I am trying to use templated `params` dict in SnwoflakeOperator. I have 2 tasks one to create a S3 object and then delete and replace the content of the table with s3 object content

```
execution_date = "{{ execution_date.int_timestamp | int }}"  # built in macro
task1 = PythonOperator(task_id='s3_create', 
          op_kwargs={'s3_key': f'{execution_date}_{file}'})

task_2 = SnowflakeOperator(task_id='load_data', 
            sql=["""copy into {{params.table}} from {{ params.stage }} 
                    files = ('{{ params.files }}') 
                    file_format = 'csv'
                 """]
            params={'table':'test_table', 
                    'files'=f'{execution_date}_{file}'}
)
task_1 >> task_2
```

It is not rendering as expected and have tried almost all formatting combinations.

Note: I cannot use `S3ToSnowflakeOperator` as I have do more than just copying the contents into the table.

Comment: What is `file`?

Comment: No, you have `f'{execution_date}_{file}'` what is file in this string?

Comment: file can be anything like `test_file.csv` @EladKalif

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with the syntax of the query that you set. is it 1 string? it seems like a wrong syntax?

Comment: yes, it is the one string (sorry for formatting) and the intention is to use jinja to render templated SQL.

Comment: OK got it. see edit of the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sql` is [templated filed](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/39e395f9816c04ef2f033eb0b4f635fc3018d803/airflow/providers/snowflake/operators/snowflake.py#L78) thus it can automatically render `execution_date` (since it's Airflow build-in macro) there is no need to set it via `params`. The `params` is used to render python variables or just strings that you want to pass.

You can just set it directly as:

```
file = "test_file.csv"
SnowflakeOperator(
    task_id='load_data',
    sql=""" copy into {{ params.table }} from {{ params.stage }}
         files = ('{{ execution_date }}_{{ params.file }}')
         file_format = csv
         """,
    params={
        'table': 'test_table',
        'stage': 'test_stage',
        'file': file
    }
)
```

It will be rendered as:
[image]

I'm not sure this is the file name you wanted but you can change `execution_date` to any other macro you wish.

**Edit:**
You can replace `{{ execution_date }}` with `{{ execution_date.int_timestamp | int }}` it will produce:
[image]

Comment: I am converting execution_date into int. In the example I have `execution_date = "{{ execution_date.int_timestamp | int }}"  # built in macro`

Comment: So in my answer just replace `{{ execution_date }}` with `{{ execution_date.int_timestamp | int }}`

Comment: I think it will work. I am testing it out with a small tweak but it should work. Thanks for the answer. I will mark as accepted after testing

Comment: Hello @EladKalif. How do you suggest templating the `params` if the SQL is a query file not a query string?